# Проблема с сортировкой структур(нужно отсортировать по баллам). Если вообще возможна сортировка при таком заполнение файла

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct list
{
    char sur[128];
    int  ball;
    int  mark;
}list;
int addstud(char *std);
int viewinfo(char *std);
int delstud(char *std,float n,int t);
int sortstud(char *std);

int main()
{
 list stud;
 int i=0,menu,t=0;
 float n=0;
 char std[] = "stud.txt";
 FILE *fl;

 while (1)
 {
    printf("1)Add new student\n2)Show list of students\n3)Change info about student\n4)Delete student\n5)Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&menu);
    switch (menu)
    {
 case 1:
        addstud(std);
        break;
 case 2:
        viewinfo(std);
        break;
case  3:
        sortstud(std);
        break;
 case 4:
        delstud(std,n,t);
        t++;
        break;

 case 5:

        return 0;
 default:
        printf("Eror, please try again!\n");
        //system("cls");
    }

 }
}

int addstud(char *std)
{
    FILE *fl;
    fl  = fopen(std, "a");
    list stud;
    if (fl == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter surname student: ");
    scanf("%s",stud.sur);
    //printf("%s",stud.sur);
    //fprintf(fl,"%-9s",stud->sur);
    printf("Enter scores of student: ");
    scanf("%d",&stud.ball);
    //printf("%d",stud.ball);
    //fprintf(fl,"%-4d",stud->ball);
    stud.mark = 0;
    fwrite(&stud,sizeof(list),1,fl);
    printf("\n");
    //fprintf(fl,"%-4d\n",stud->mark);
    fclose(fl);
    printf("Press Enter for continue...\n");
    //getch();
    //system("cls");
    return(0);
}
int sortstud(char *std)
{
    FILE *fl;
    int j = 0,i = 0, n = 0;
    list stud[10];
    int temp;
    list studt;
    fl = fopen(std,"r+b");
    fseek(fl,0,SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(fl);
    fseek(fl,0,SEEK_SET);
    int sizefile = sizeof(list);
    n = (size/sizefile);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        fscanf(fl,"%i",studt.ball);
        stud[i].ball = studt.ball;
        printf("EBAL:=%i",stud[i].ball);
    }

    for (j = 0;j<n-1;j++)
    {
        for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            if (stud[i].ball < stud[i+1].ball)
            {
                printf("EPTA!:");
                temp = stud[i].ball;
                printf("TEMP=%i",temp);
                stud[i].ball = stud[i+1].ball;
                printf("STUD1=%i",stud[i].ball);
                stud[i+1].ball = temp;
                printf("STUD2=%i",stud[i+1].ball);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fl);
}
```

Comment: а поля mark и sur кто будет обменивать? с другой стороны, может использовать встроенный qsort?

Comment: не могли бы вы привести пример кода с qsort... не особо понимаю как это сделать:(

Answer (score 1):

Сортировка делается [вот так](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm).

Для начала объявляется специальная функция-компаратор

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
   return ( ((list*)a)->ball - ((list*)b)->ball );
}
```

и вся сортировка теперь выглядит где то так

```
qsort(stud, n, sizeof(list), cmpfunc);
```